# Thinktecture Identity Server password reset redirect

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

In my environment I have presently two applications, lets call them portal and sso. Portal is where I manage user accounts and allow people to register.  SSO is my implementation of IdentityServer.  I want to require users to reset their password after 90 days or after they had their password recovered for them.  I can check for this in the AuthenticateLocalAsync function,  but the question is how do I redirect them to the portal password reset page?  Or is it easier to add a custom page to the IdentityServer to handle password resets of this nature?  Are there any examples of this, specifically where the identityserver is not embedded into the application using its login functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to create a "reset password" page in the same IdentityServer project, and issue a partial login redirecting to that page every time an user with expired password completes the sign on process successfully.

With this approach you can catch users with expired password before they are effectively logged in, without completely breaking the login flow.

You can find some details in the [IdentityServer3 CustomUserService sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomUserService/CustomUserService), specifically in the "EULA" sample which uses "EulaAtLoginUserService".

I do not think there is a way to directly redirect the user to an external endpoint (e.g. your Portal residing in another domain) during the IdentityServer login flow.